# Method comparing two strings never returns proper results

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, stringbuilder

This is a separate problem lingering from a previous question I asked here on SO.

I've posted a copy of my full source at [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/822727/d3d281cc4ec990a644a040218e8c6095a920a698) and I only have one lingering problem that I can't resolve.

`FindLine()` always returns -1.  I have confirmed that the two variables are getting passed good data, so I can't figure out why the comparisons never return anything other than -1.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code if you don't want to check out the full source:

```
DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
string ImportPath = @"***PATH***\***INFILE***.csv";
string QueryString = "SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(MP.Symbol) AS Symbol, LOWER(MP.SecType) AS SecType, MBI.Status FROM MoxySecMaster AS MP LEFT JOIN MoxyBondInfo AS MBI ON MP.Symbol = MBI.Symbol AND MP.SecType = MBI.SecType WHERE MP.SecType <> 'caus' AND MP.SecType IS NOT NULL AND MP.Symbol IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Symbol ASC;";
string symb = "";
StringBuilder OrigText = new StringBuilder();
SqlConnection MoxyConn = new SqlConnection("server=***;database=***;user id=***;password=***");
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryString, MoxyConn);

MoxyConn.Open();
resultTable = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(resultTable);
MoxyConn.Close();
OrigText.Append(File.ReadAllText(ImportPath));

char[] tempSymb = new char[10];
OrigText.CopyTo(0, tempSymb, 0, OrigText.ToString().IndexOf(",", 0));
symb = new string(tempSymb);
int foundSpot = FindLine(symb, resultTable);
```

... and ...

```
static int FindLine(string symbol, DataTable symbolList)
{
    for (int vcl = 0; vcl < symbolList.Rows.Count; vcl++)
    {
        if (symbolList.Rows[vcl][0].ToString() == symbol.ToUpper())
            return vcl;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Put a trace in the function to print both the operands in the comparison to the console to throw some light on this...

Comment: I think string comparison be a well tested function. Trace the code as suggested by Gishu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using this:

```
if (String.Equals(symbolList.Rows[vcl][0].ToString().Trim(),
   symbol, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: BAM!  Thank you!  Now before you go solve someone else's problem would you mind checking back here in ten or fifteen minutes if I have any questions about why this works?  I need to read through the .Equals() info first.

Comment: Presumably symb will end up padded to ten characters with the null character \0 which is why the == does not work.